# How to run Firefox jailed without serious performance loss?

Tags: linux, firefox, security, performance, xvfb

My Firefox configuration is tricky:

1. Firefox runs at separate restricted user account which cannot connect to main X server.
2. Firefox uses Xvfb (virtual "headless" X server) as X server.
3. x11vnc is running on that Xvfb.
4. On the main X server there is vncviewer running that connect to this x11vnc

On powerful laptop (Acer Extensa 5220) it seems to work more or less well, but on "Acer Aspire One" netbook it is slowish (on a background that firefox is loaded with lots of extensions).

How to optimise this scheme? Requirements:

1. Browser cannot connect to main X server.
2. Browser should be in chroot jail (no "suid" scripts, readonly for many things)
3. Browser should have a lot of features (like in AutoPager, NoScript, WoT, AdBlockPlus)

Comment: IMHO, X11 separation is just paranoia.

Comment: @grawity, Browser is expected to be affected by various security exploits. If browser runs malicious native code, it can connect to X server and input commands there, so gain elevated access. I don't want main browser to be a trusted component.

Comment: @Vi. You may find http://qubes-os.org/ interesting, it is an OS based on xen + small virtualized linux guests, and guests can't access the main X server directly. Basically, it implements everything you want (including separate virtual hard disk instead of a chroot), but evrything's pre-configured for you :) .

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron, How to attain decent GUI performance without giving direct access to X server? The main questoin is what to put between X and the browser.

Comment: Well, I know little about qubes-os, but it seems that they use a custom protocol to communicate efficiently between the Xorg in the VM and the Xorg on the host. You should definitely read this page : http://wiki.qubes-os.org/trac/wiki/GUIdocs even if you don't agree with some of their implementation choices, it may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) as the X11 server.

Another possibility is to run Firefox over a SSH connection to `localhost`, with restricted X11 forwarding. The OpenSSH `ssh` client has options [`ForwardX11` and `ForwardX11Trusted`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5); disable the latter in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Will SSH approach it prevent Firefox from running things like x11vnc and controlling all application connected to the same X server?

Comment: @Vi: [Untrusted clients will not have access](http://docs.google.com/viewer?q=cache:v-D_iKG4I3wJ:www.xfree86.org/current/security.pdf) to windows created by any other program.