# How do I limit X access for potentially malicious GUI application?

Tags: linux, security, xorg

Application directly accessing Xorg can not just draw some good behaving windows, but also capture input, mask windows something else (e.g. password input), lock X server and so on.

How can I give an application (which is already running with secured network and filesystem) a *limited* access to X? How to secure X from potentially insecure GUI application (like a web browser or email client) without causing too much overhead?

I currently know two methods:

- VNC to localhost. This is high-overhead approach.
- Usage of Quebes: http://wiki.qubes-os.org/trac/wiki/GUIdocs. But it's too intrusive and not arch-independent. I want only `qubes_gui` and `qubes_guid` from there.

Are there other ways do it?

(Related: [How to run Firefox jailed without serious performance loss?](https://superuser.com/questions/247973/how-to-run-firefox-jailed-without-serious-performance-loss))